# Google Plus API people list return nothing on server after login in client

Tags: google-api, google-plus-signin

I have a web client that signin in Google and send oauthtoken to the server:

```
//Api google plus
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); 
        po.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();

    function onLoadCallback(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyBXXXXXX'); //set your API KEY
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1',function(){});//Load Google + API
    }

    $scope.loginGooglePlus = function() {
      var myParams = {
        'clientid' : 'XXXXXXX',
        'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
        'callback': $scope.loginGooglePlusCallback,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
      };
      gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
    }

    $scope.loginGooglePlusCallback = function(result){
        if(result['status']['signed_in']){ 
            //alert("Login Success");
            console.log(result);
            UserAuth.loginGooglePlus(result.access_token);
        }   
    }
```

So, on server I try to get the people friend list thus:

```
String graphFace = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&access_token=" + oauthToken;

                urlAccess = new URL(graphFace);
                URLConnection faceConnection = urlAccess.openConnection();
                faceConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8;");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(faceConnection.getInputStream()));

                String fileJson = "", strJson = "";
                while ((strJson = in.readLine()) != null)
                    fileJson = fileJson + strJson + "\n";

                createFriendTopologyFromGoogle(person, fileJson);
```

The people list always comes empty. But if I do the same command in API Explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list) all works fine.

Do This command people list only works on client?

Comment: Are you sure that's not returning an error and not just coming up empty.   People.list requires authentication which means you should be sending access_token not Key

Comment: Yes, I get access_token in client and send to server. The jsons shows totalItems: 0 and items []

Comment: The service return always.

Json: {
 "kind": "plus#peopleFeed",
 "etag": "\"xw0en60W6-NurXn4VBU-CMjSPEw/ObDqMibaPxXUs7wb-vH72G2zQbI\"",
 "title": "Google+ List of Visible People",
 "totalItems": 0,
 "items": []
}

I have two users. User1 is friend of the user2 and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?key={APIKey}
```

will return

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Because it requires authentication try sending the following

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?access_token={Token from oauth2 authentcation}
```

Comment: I send the access_token. This key tag is unnecessary.

Comment: Do I need other permission on server?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem entering in https://plus.google.com/u/0/apps and freeing all permissions to my app. I do this on the 2 users.

Now, I need to login the users already with this permissions. I don't know this part.